# VSCode Intellisense: can we add keywords to an "exclude" list that won't be auto-completed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm writing C code in VSCode with the amazing Tab Out extension that let you tab out of brackets, quotes etc. Together with the automatically added end brackets that VSCode has,I feel very comfortable writing C code when I can just do tab, tab, semi-conlon to end a line. However, every time I try to write `self` at the end near the `)`, I can't tab out without it being changed to `STDERR_FILENO` due to autocompletion.

How can I add a word, such as `self`, so that Intellisense will not autocomplete it? Is there a list of "excluded" words that I can tell Intellisense to not mess with?

I don't want to turn off any of the autocomplete stuff, I just want some very specific keywords to not be replaced when I tab out of stuff. I also don't want to stop using tab to autocomplete. these features are all very handy.

My current work-around is defining a new code snippet in the C snippet file:

```json
"self": {
        "body": "self",
        "prefix": "self",
        "description": "this is to prevent stupid suggestions for the keyword self"
    }
```

but I consider this an ugly fix so let me know if you can help!